# how to reuse the memory for bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap

My app will generate a big bitmap(1024*800)(the music score in pad), since the bitmap's height is different for different music, So I have to create a bitmap for when activity start, sometimes it throw OOM exception, So I would like to find a way to reuse the old bitmap's memory for new bitmap? I can not use static variable Bitmap, because the height is different for different music.

Answer (score 2):

To release the memory of an image, use following API,

```
bitmap.recycle();
```

This is the only way to control memory. There isn't a way to reuse the memory.